# Web.Config for Forms Authentication, Locations not available to anonymous users

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I'm having trouble getting my web.config to allow anonymous user access to a couple of pages.
Any pointers as to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

The following shows where I declare my authentication and authorization sections

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

The following shows my location section which I though should allow anonymous access to the page

```
<location path ="Default.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: The comment to competent_tech's answer suggests that this issue is still a problem, but you have accepted the answer - is the problem now solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the allow users to:

```
<allow users="*"/>
```

In order to specify that any user can access this page.

Comment: That setting should work (just verified against one of our web.configs). The most likely cause in that case is that you don't have IIS configured for anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

Add to web.config:

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

and for all folders containing css, javascripts, images on Login.aspx add:

```
<location path="CssFolder">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```